# Securely sending photos from the client's webcam to the server

Tags: javascript, security, post, http-post, webcam-capture

In my web application, I need to be able to take pictures from the webcam to confirm the user's identity. I use the function getMediaStream, take photo and send it with POST request. But as far as I know, everything that is done on the client side of the application can be subjected to reverse engineering, and people can catch the moment of sending, and replace the real image with the photo of another person. How can the most secure way to send camera photos to the server?

Answer (score 0):

You could send the picture in an encrypted zip file over https. 
Encrypt and decrypt the file with a password that is only known by the user and the server.

Comment: User can replace photos before encryption, if it will be on client side

Comment: The only possibility i know, to disable Object manipulation, is Object.freeze().